# Using logical operators to determine cell value is greater than one before and after

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, boolean, operators

I have a a column of data in an Excel sheet and want to filter those values where a cell has a value greater than the previous or the next cell. eg for ColumnA my logic is:

```
If (A2>A1 & A2>A3)
Then B2=1
Else B2=0
```

I need to execute it for 1,000 rows in column A so something like:

> if(currentcellnum value > currentcellnum-1 value and currentcellnum> currentcellvaluve+1)

then print in adjacent column of current cell `1` else `0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit shorter than @Uberzen1's (first) answer:

```
=(A2>A1)*(A2>A3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Type these formulas in cell B2 and drag down as far as you need them:

if you want to return 1 when the value is greater than both:

```
=IF(AND(A2>A1,A2>A3),1,0)
```

if you want to return 1 when the value is greater than either:

```
=IF(OR(A2>A1,A2>A3),1,0)
```